# Send receipt when I create membership does not seem to work (CiviCRM 5.67.0)

Tags: civimember, receipts

I don't understand why when I add a membership and I check "Send Confirmation and Receipt" I don't receive the receipt.

[image]

On the other hand, if I use "Send Receipt" from the action menu of the contribution, it works (the receipt is sent).

[image]

I'm using CiviCRM 5.67.0 on WorpPres (I don't tried with previous versions)

Comment: Hi Masetto. My guess is that something is amiss with your Message Templates, and as you can see here https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/messageTemplates?reset=1#/workflow there are different ones for Contribution v Membership, and for On-line and Off-line. And that your Off-line Membership one isn't firing. If you have never modified these then this is unlikely to be the problem, but is first thing I would check.

Comment: Hi @petednz-fuzion, I don't have modified these templates. The "Send receipt" action in contribution joined to a membership uses the "Memberships - Receipt (on-line)" template. I tried with 2 different installations of CiviCRM 5.67.0 and I have the same problem. In another installation, but version 5.66.2 on Drupal, this works.
The odd thing is that the "Receipt Sent" of the contribution is filled, but the email was not sent.

Comment: and have you checked the server mail logs (or however you are sending)?

Comment: of course. In fact, when I "Send Receipt" from the action menu of the contribution, it works (the receipt is sent).